# How to get all images from HTML control in Flex?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a HTML control in Flex that succefully loads a page. 
Is there someway that i can extract or get all the images from that HTML control and show them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use the HTML document DOM and ask about all img tags. It's a lot cleaner this way.

Once you get the DOM it's all standard so you can check [HTML DOM documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) if you're unsure about something.

Here's quick example. I'll just write the onComplete function, as it would be called in Taurayi's example

```
var _imagesSrc:Array= [];
private function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = e.target as HTMLLoader;
    var doc:* = htmlLoader.window.document; //use void (*) type for DOM objects
    var imgTags:* = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
    if(imgTags)
    {
        for(var i:int=0;i<imgTags.length;i++)
        {
            var src:* = imgTags[i].getAttribute("src"); //not sure about return type here, could also be a String
            if(src)
                _imagesSrc.push(src.toString());
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well an idea would be that you load the html page using `HTMLLoader` and then when it has loaded you get the source. Then using a parser or regex you would extract the values of the `src` attributes of the `<img />` tags. The values of the `src` attributes will be the urls to the images on the page you loaded. Then using `Loader` and said urls, you would load them into your flash application.

Here's an example:

**Main.as(document class)**:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {   
            var htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
            htmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            htmlLoader.width = stage.stageWidth;
            htmlLoader.height = stage.stageHeight;
            htmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.wampserver.com/"));

        }// end function

        private function onComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            var htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = e.target as HTMLLoader;
            var body:String = htmlLoader.window.document.body.outerHTML;
            var imgTags:Array = getImgTags(body);
            var src:String = getSrc(imgTags[1]);

            trace(src); // output: http://www.wampserver.com/wp-content/themes/wampserver/img/home-title.png


            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(src));

        }// end function

        private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            var loader:Loader = (e.target as LoaderInfo).loader;
            addChild(loader);

        }// end function

        private function getImgTags(source:String):Array
        {
            return source.match(/(<img.*?>)/g);

        }// end function

        private function getSrc(imgTag:String):String
        {
            return imgTag.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1];

        }// end function

    }// end class


}// end package
```

Keep in mind this is just an idea, there are some obvious flaws.

Comment: Looks good :) Thanks! I will try the DOM objects method first to see if that one works.